# How to check if text exists in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I would like to check if '64' exists on the page which I have created.

```
const x = Selector('.FilterCockpit--header--count').withText('64');
```

The following test fails.

```
test('x', async t => {
    await t
    .expect((x).exists).ok()
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="FilterCockpit--header--results">
          <span class="FilterCockpit--header--count">
              64
         </span>
         Results
 </div>
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I get error message in console: AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

Answer (score 5):

I've executed your test case with the latest TestCafe of version 1.1.4 and it is passed:

[image]

Here are my complete test case and a test file based on your code snippets:

```
import { Selector} from 'testcafe';

fixture('fixture')
    .page('file:///Temp/56074194.html');

const x = Selector('.FilterCockpit--header--count').withText('64');

test('x', async t => {

    await t
        .expect((x).exists).ok()
});
```

56074194.html

```
<div class="FilterCockpit--header--results">
          <span class="FilterCockpit--header--count">
              64
         </span>
         Results
 </div>
```

Perhaps, there are some circumstances that may break the test execution. If there are any additional steps I need to perform, please let me know.

See also: [Check if an Element Exists](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists)

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you very much for your answer. It works fine now.

Comment: You are welcome. This is great news. I'm happy to hear that you have figured out how to resolve the issue.